# NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() throws exception with null message string

Tags: android, ip-address

I picked up some old code of mine to rebuild and one of the methods that used to work on my tablet and phone no longer works.  I'm trying to use a routine I picked up here to get my IP address.

When the program executes line 4 (starting with "for (Enumeration..." it immediately jumps to the exception catch section.  The exception has no message and for the string the ex.getMessage() returns null.  The exception number is 830034796568 (decimal).

Here's the code.  As mentioned this worked fine a year ago.

Thanks for any help!

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    String address= null;
    try {  
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                address = new String(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && address.length() < 18) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        String msg = ex.getMessage();
        //do nothing
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you wrap the SocketException in a RuntimeException and rethrow it so we can see the full stacktrace?

Comment: I changed it to "throw RuntimeException(ex);  The stacktrace shown by the Eclipse debugger is null.   I'm a bit new to this and rusty to boot.  Is there something I can do to show the information that will help others help me?

Comment: I was allowing permission for android.permission.INTERNET, but missed android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

Answer (score 23):

Just to clarify with a full answer.

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
```

throws a `SocketException` if the application is missing this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In my tests (on Android 4.4.2) `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` can be skipped.

Comment: But I can have interfaces without internet, is there any way to get network interfaces without interface permission